# Populate cell based on unique values from two fields

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a data set similar to the google sheet image below. I currently have a formula in column C that populates the first unique value in column B.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(IF(B2:B="""",,IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), ""<=""&ROW(B2:B))=1, 1, )))
```

However I need a formula to return what is in column D. This populates the cell for the first row that has both a unique 'Color' and 'Name'. For example, row 2 is populated for Purple - James and row 12 for White - James. But row 38 for Purple - James is not populated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=map(A2:A, B2:B, lambda(color, name, 
  if( 
    rows(filter(B2:name, A2:color = color, B2:name = name)) = 1, 
    1, 
    iferror(ø) 
  ) 
))
```

If you just want to get a list of unique color-name pairs, use this:

```
=unique(A2:B)
```

See [map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985), [filter()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) and [unique()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198).